# java util logging.properties: How to log to two different files

Tags: java, tomcat, java.util.logging

I am placing a logging.properties in the WEB-INF/classes dir of tomcat

I would like to log to two different files. For example: org.pkg1 goes to one file and org.pkg2 goes to a separate file.

I can get one file configured, but not two. Is that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787317/two-log4j-files-for-ear-with-two-modules

tonsn more, just search stackoverflow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally figured this out. In tomcat they extend java util logging ("JULI") to enable this functionality. Here's a logging.properties file that I put in the WEB-INF directory that finally accomplished what I was after......:

```
handlers=1console.java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, 2jsp.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3financials.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
.handlers=1a.java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

jsp.level=ALL
jsp.handlers=2jsp.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
org.apache.jasper.level = FINE
org.apache.jasper.handlers=2jsp.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
org.apache.jsp.level = FINE
org.apache.jsp.handlers=2jsp.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

com.paypal.level=ALL
com.paypal.handlers=3financials.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

3financials.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level=ALL
3financials.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory=${catalina.base}/logs
3financials.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix=financials.

2jsp.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level=ALL
2jsp.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory=${catalina.base}/logs
2jsp.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix=jsp.

1console.java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
1console.java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Answer (score 8):

Speaking of logging.properties configuration, I did not found any mechanism to use more that one appender. I made simple workaround that works for me.

```
public class CustomAFileHandler extends FileHandler {
   public DebugFileHandler() throws IOException, SecurityException {
      super();
   }
}

public class CustomBFileHandler extends FileHandler {
   public DebugFileHandler() throws IOException, SecurityException {
      super();
   }
}
```

And my logging.properties

```
...
handlers=<pkg_name>.CustomAFileHandler, <pkg_name>.CustomBFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

<pkg_name>.CustomAFileHandler.level=ALL
<pkg_name>.CustomAFileHandler.pattern=%h/A%u.log
<pkg_name>.CustomAFileHandler.limit=50000
<pkg_name>.CustomAFileHandler.count=1 
<pkg_name>.CustomAFileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


<pkg_name>.CustomBFileHandler.level=ALL
<pkg_name>.CustomBFileHandler.pattern=%h/B%u.log
<pkg_name>.CustomBFileHandler.limit=50000
<pkg_name>.CustomBFileHandler.count=1 
<pkg_name>.CustomBFileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to get two handlers of the same type with java.util.logging classes that have different arguments.  Probably the simplest way to do this is to create a FileHandler subclass in your logging.properties that passes the appropriate arguments to enable your logging to take place, such as:

```
org.pkg1.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
org.pkg2.handlers=org.pkg2.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern="org_pkg1_%u.%g.log"
org.pkg2.FileHandler.pattern="org_pkg2_%u.%g.log"
```

org/pkg2/FileHandler.java:

```
package org.pkg2;

import java.util.logging.*;

public class FileHandler extends java.util.logging.FileHandler {
    public FileHandler() {
        super(LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty("org.pkg2.FileHandler.pattern"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using pure jdk also (try with jdk 7 or jdk 8).

Just create custom file handler; use that similar to "java.util.logging.FileHandler".

```
public class JULTestingFileHandler extends FileHandler {

    public JULTestingFileHandler() throws IOException, SecurityException 
    {
        super();    
    }
}
```

user properties file;

```
com.xxx.handlers = com.xxx.JULXXXFileHandler

com.xxx.JULXXXFileHandler.pattern   = ./logs/test1_test2.%u.%g.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem myself with `java.util.logging` and not quite satisfied with the given answers, I just found in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html):

> 2.2 Changing the Configuration
>
> Here's a small program that dynamically adjusts the logging
>   configuration to send output to a specific file and to get lots of
>   information on wombats. The pattern "%t" means the system temporary
>   directory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Handler fh = new FileHandler("%t/wombat.log");
        Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
        Logger.getLogger("com.wombat").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        ...
    }
```

So, it seems you can't do it just from the .properties file as can't instantiate several appenders, but you can do it programmatically. Also it should be possible using the [`LoggerManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html)