# Logging to different files using single logging.properties

Tags: java, logging

I'm trying to configure the logging.properties file that is shared between multiple applications. I want a specific log file for a class of mine, but I don't want other logs (from other classes) to be included in the file.

How can I achieve this by only modifying the logging.properties file?

I have the following logging.properties file:

```
############################################################
#   Default Logging Configuration File
#
# You can use a different file by specifying a filename
# with the java.util.logging.config.file system property.  
# For example java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myfile
############################################################
############################################################
#   Global properties
############################################################
# "handlers" specifies a comma separated list of log Handler 
# classes.  These handlers will be installed during VM startup.
# Note that these classes must be on the system classpath.
# By default we only configure a ConsoleHandler, which will only
# show messages at the INFO and above levels.
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# To also add the FileHandler, use the following line instead.
#handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# Default global logging level.
# This specifies which kinds of events are logged across
# all loggers.  For any given facility this global level
# can be overriden by a facility specific level
# Note that the ConsoleHandler also has a separate level
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.
.level= INFO
############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################
# default file output is in user's home directory.
```

**java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/default.log (all the logs are currently going to this file)**

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
```

**my.class.logger.level = INFO (I want this class to log to the file /home/myuser/myclass.log)**

```
other.class.logger.level = ALL
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639694/java-util-logging-properties-how-to-log-to-two-different-files

Comment: Thanks @StefanLindenberg, although that's with Tomcat. Is there a way to do it without using specific libraries from Tomcat? I mean, with standard Java libraries?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using pure jdk also (try with jdk 7 or jdk 8).

Just create custom file handler; use that similar to `java.util.logging.FileHandler` and extend it.

```
public class JULTestingFileHandler extends FileHandler {

    public JULTestingFileHandler() throws IOException, SecurityException 
    {
        super();    
    }
}
```

user properties file;

```
com.xxx.handlers = com.xxx.JULXXXFileHandler

com.xxx.JULXXXFileHandler.pattern   = ./logs/test1_test2.%u.%g.log
```