# Custom logging handler in Glassfish needs application name

Tags: java, logging, glassfish

I'm extending the java.util.logging.Handler class for creating a custom logger in Glassfish 3.
We have several applications running in the Glassfish domain and we want to have the name of the application within the log file text.

But for the java.util.logging.LogRecord class I cannot find any attribute to do that.

If you have any ideas please let me know.

I also tried to change the properties of the default server.log file - but without success.

**How can I have different log files or log entries for each application?**

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639694/java-util-logging-properties-how-to-log-to-two-different-files ?

Comment: Yes. But I this case I have to configure a logging handler for each application manually. I want to keep it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a [javax.servlet.ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that uses [javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletContextName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletContextName()) to get the application name from the web.xml deployment descriptor.

You can then use this value in your own [java.util.logging.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) implementation (perhaps derived from SimpleFormatter).