# How can I use different Log Files to each webapp Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, logging, tomcat7

I'm using Tomcat7 and I have 2 webapp on the same server.
I want separate log for each of them.

How can I do it??

Comment: This SO post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639694/java-util-logging-properties-how-to-log-to-two-different-files